# Changing size and color of a Text on version 9

Tags: front-end

I am running v9 on mac pro and think that I am doing something wrong.

When commenting the solution of a particular exercise I add a text cell (command 7) and type the comment which is nothing more than a sentence with some mathematical expressions (control ( - expression-  control )).

To change the size and color of the whole comment, I simply highlight it and Format - Size or Color - to the desired size and color.  The change does not apply to whole comment! Why? (I think that is due to the expressions).

For instance, if the comment is as follows

> Here is an example, if $P = 1$ then the whole solution depends on the number of ...

the change applies up to $P = 1$.  The rest of the sentence is unchanged.

Many thanks

Ed

Comment: You're right - this looks like another bug in version 9. You could perhaps work around it by selecting the cell bracket before changing the format. But I agree that doesn't allow you to make arbitrary local changes.

Comment: @Jens - Many many thanks.  Selecting the cell works just fine but the arbitrary local changes do not.

Comment: @Kuba OK, done.

Answer (score 2):

To make the comment into an answer: You're right - this looks like another bug in version 9. You could perhaps work around it by selecting the cell bracket before changing the format. But I agree that doesn't allow you to make arbitrary local changes.